# [Vue.js]Namespacing in vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to namespacing modules' getters、mutations、actions，I see this [document here](http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html#namespacing), but it seems little bit vague.

```js
// types.js

// define names of getters, actions and mutations as constants
// and they are prefixed by the module name `todos`
export const DONE_COUNT = 'todos/DONE_COUNT'
export const FETCH_ALL = 'todos/FETCH_ALL'
export const TOGGLE_DONE = 'todos/TOGGLE_DONE'
// modules/todos.js
import * as types from '../types'

// define getters, actions and mutations using prefixed names
const todosModule = {
  state: { todos: [] },

  getters: {
    [types.DONE_COUNT] (state) {
      // ...
    }
  },

  actions: {
    [types.FETCH_ALL] (context, payload) {
      // ...
    }
  },

  mutations: {
    [types.TOGGLE_DONE] (state, payload) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

And then how do I use moduled getters、mutations in vue components?

```js
export default {
  data() {
    // like this?
    count: this.$store.getters.DONE_COUNT, 
    // ?
    count: this.$store.getters.todos.DONE_COUNT,
    // ?
    count: this.$store.getters.todosModule.DONE_COUNT,
    // ?
    count: ?,
  },
};
```

Comment: solved the problem by using mapGetters in 'vuex'

Answer (score 4):

```
this.$store.getters['todos/DONE_COUNT']
```